# Making one query to join multiple tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables:

1. Nutritions table which is static table that have all nutrition `nutrition_id` and `nutrition_name`
2. Products table which has products info and the columns are `product_id`, `product_name`, `brand`
3. `product_nutritions` which is mediator table that links the product with it's nutrition facts with their values . The structure is `product_id`, `nutrition_id`, `nutrition_value`. Each product can have 1 row or more depending on the number of nutrition facts it has.

Here is a real test example

---

Nutritions table

```
nutrition_id |nutrition_name
           1 | caloreis    
           2 | fat    
           3 | sugar    
           4 | salt
```

---

Products table

```
product_id| product_name           | brand   
        1 | Nutella Hazelnut Cocoa | Nutella    
        2 | Nutella Jar            | Nutella
```

---

product_nutrition table

```
product_id | nutrition_id | nutrition_value
         1 |            1 |             200
         1 |            2 |              15
         1 |            3 |               2
         1 |            4 |              11
         2 |            1 |             200
         2 |            2 |              15
         2 |            3 |              12
         2 |            4 |              11
```

But I need to create a query that returns the products' name along with the nutrition facts that belong to a specific brand, where the value of sugar is less than 5.

Here is the query I have tried but

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM products pi
 INNER JOIN product_nutrition_facts pn ON pi.product_id = pn.product_id
 WHERE pn.nutrition_id
 IN (
 '2,4,1'
 )
 OR (
  pn.nutrition_value <=5
  AND pn.nutrition_id =3
 )
 HAVING p.brand ='Nutella'
 ORDER BY `pn`.`nutrition_id` DESC 
 LIMIT 0 , 10
```

The code returns the products that doesn't even have sugar in the nutrition facts label!

Can somebody help please?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service** So what have you tried so far. Show us, you may not be so far off the solution already.

Comment: I have post my query. But it's not correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    p.brand,
    p.product_name,
    n.nutrition_name,
    pn.nutrition_value
FROM
    product_nutritions pn,
    Products p,
    Nutritions n
WHERE
    pn.nutrition_id = n.nutrition_id
        AND pn.product_id = p.product_id
        AND p.brand = 'Nutella'
        AND n.nutrition_name = 'sugar'
        AND pn.nutrition_value <= 5;
```

**EDIT : Try this :**

   `SELECT 
        p.brand,
        p.product_name,
        n.nutrition_name,
        pn.nutrition_value
    FROM
        product_nutritions pn,
        Products p,
        Nutritions n
    WHERE
        pn.nutrition_id = n.nutrition_id
        AND pn.product_id = p.product_id
        AND p.id IN (
        SELECT 
           p.id
        FROM
            product_nutritions pn,
            Products p,
            Nutritions n
        WHERE
            pn.nutrition_id = n.nutrition_id
            AND pn.product_id = p.product_id
            AND p.brand = 'Nutella'
            AND n.nutrition_name = 'sugar'
            AND pn.nutrition_value <= 5
        );`

**For multiple nutriments, you could do something like this :**

   `SELECT 
        p.brand,
        p.product_name,
        n.nutrition_name,
        pn.nutrition_value
    FROM
        product_nutritions pn,
        Products p,
        Nutritions n
    WHERE
        pn.nutrition_id = n.nutrition_id
        AND pn.product_id = p.product_id
        AND p.id IN (
        SELECT 
           p.id
        FROM
            product_nutritions pn,
            Products p,
            Nutritions n
        WHERE
            pn.nutrition_id = n.nutrition_id
            AND pn.product_id = p.product_id
            AND 
            (
               (
                p.brand = 'Nutella'
                AND n.nutrition_name = 'sugar'
                AND pn.nutrition_value <= 5
               ) OR (
                p.brand = 'Nutella'
                AND n.nutrition_name = 'whatever'
                AND pn.nutrition_value <= whatevernumber
            )
        );`

`

Comment: This will return only sugar in nutrition facts and I need the product with all nutrition facts with value of sugar is less than specific value

Comment: can you please suggest me if I need to filter by 2 nutrition facts, I have tried <code> AND n.nutrition_name = 'sugar'
            AND pn.nutrition_value <= 5 AND AND n.nutrition_name = 'salt'
            AND pn.nutrition_value <= 10 </code> but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

i am not an sql specialist , but i think this should help.
https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/62086/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001361784.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` statement

```
SELECT products.name as productName, nutrition.nutrition_name as NutritionName, product_nutrition.nutrition_value 
FROM product_nutrition 
INNER JOIN products on products.id = product_nutrition.product_id 
INNER JOIN Nutritions on Nutritions.id=product_nutrition.nutrition_id 
WHERE product_nutrition.nutrition_value = 'any value you want'
```

Comment: How can I specify sugar is less than specific value?

Comment: where product_nutrition.nutrition_value<5  and you can select by name of product of name of nutrition by these where statement where product_nutrition.nutrition_value<5 and products.name =''  Nutella Jar   "

Comment: where nutritions.nutrition_name="sugar " and product_nutrition.nutrition_value< 5this will return all sugar with value less than 5

Comment: I don't want to return all sugars, I want to return all nutrition facts including sugar less than 5